# end variable name in string w/ double quotes

Tags: php

Have I missed something in my years of php or is there no way to do this:

```
$var = "testString";
echo "$varAndRestOfStringConctd";
// testStringAndRestOfStringConctd
```

Is there any other way of writing that besides:

```
echo $var.'AndRestOfStringConctd';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTM ~ http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

```
echo "{$var}AndRestOfStringConctd";
```

An alternative is the often forgotten `printf` / `sprintf` functionality

```
printf('%sAndRestOfStringConctd', $var);
```

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds mate!

Comment: I'm going to mark this correct because of the resource.  Thanks.  I knew it was simple!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use braces.

```
echo "${var}AndRestOfStringConctd";
```

Comment: Almost didn't recognise you. How old is that photo ;)

Comment: I was but a young lad of 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the variable in curly brackets/braces:

```
$var = "testString";
echo "{$var}AndRestOfStringConctd";
```

That tells PHP where the variable ends.

Comment: Just curious... Is there any reason why mine was downvoted when it is correct?

Comment: Aren't these brackets? [ ]  That's the only thing I could see potentially wrong with the answer.

Comment: @miken32 Technically `{` and `}` are *curly* brackets or braces as some refer to them, but they are brackets nonetheless.  I'll edit it to be more specific.

Comment: @miken32 [*Bracket*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Terminology_and_names_for_various_symbols) is quite a nebulous term